# What attack does the "state" parameter in OpenID Connect server flow prevent?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, csrf, openid-connect

Not sure what kind of CSRF attack prevents the "state" parameter in OpenID Connect server flow. Could someone give me an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It prevents an attack where the attacker produces a fake authentication response, e.g. as part of the Basic Client Profile by sending a `code` to the Client's redirect URI. For example: after phishing the user an attacker could inject a stolen `code` that would be associated with the current user in this way. The `state` correlates request and response so an unsolicited crafted response is not possible without knowing the `state` parameter that was used in the request.

Comment: Hans, if I understand correctly the only risk would be that "Alice" will be logued to attacker's account. Is this correct?

Comment: that is a typical OAuth-for-login risk, yes, but there are more advanced attacks that would allow the other way around as well where the attacker logs in as Alice; that presumes a stolen `code` from Alice through a different attack but not having CSRF protection allows for an easy exploit of that `code`

Answer (score 10):

By comparing the `state`value on the authorization request and response, the idea is to be able validate that the authorization response is correlated with the request.

So far so good; but what is stopping an adversary from forging an authorization response using a stolen authorization code from a benign user? The OpenID client has no way of validating, that the authorization code is correlated with the `state` value. IMHO, it would be better to use the `nonce` field in the authorization request as this is echoed inside the signed `id_token` once the authorization code has been exchanged. Now, the OpenID client can unambiguously correlate the `id_token` (the proof of authorization) with the authorization request.

This way, we mitigate both CSRF and replay attacks. Or have I overlooked something here?

Honestly I am a little puzzled why the OpenID Connect [specs](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) "recommends" use of `state` but leaves `nonce` optional.

Answer (score 6):

That advice comes from OAuth2 and following it blocks the ability to support an "IdP-initiated" flow.

OIDC is all about SSO'ing into the RP's (Relying Party; AKA "Client") system because they're authenticated at the IdP's (Identity Provider; AKA "Provider") system---and there's some backend trust setup between the 2 systems.

So you've got an "Authentication Request". This is the redirect from the RP to the IdP; it's got the "scope=openid" in the Url's query string. Then you have an "Authentication Response"; it's got the "code=XXXXX" in the Url's query string. In **both** of these GET requests, the browser/end-user is **anonymous** in the eyes of the RP. It is only after the RP validates the "code" (on the backend) that the RP assigns identity (authentication) to the browser.

This means that the **only** way State can be used to attempt to prevent CSRF is if the RP's application stores that State value in the browser to uniquely identify it. Then, when a browser comes to the RP with a Code and State, it can make sure the browser had previously attempted an Authentication Request. But the RP can never guarantee that the Code came from a specific request; the State can potentially be replayed within the context of that browser.

It also means that, instead of using State, the RP could mitigate a CSRF attack by checking that the HTTP "Referrer" header indicates that the "Authentication Response" came from the expected IdP.

**What do you gain from using State in this manner?**

The **only** actual attack vector you have mitigated is the possibility of making person A use person B's Code to login to SiteX instead of their own. In other words, Alice can theoretically have Bob follow a link and log Bob in as herself.

As far as I'm aware, at this point, you've either got the OIDC exchange running in an iFrame---and the attacker has found some way to exploit that---or you have a problem with the browser's Same-Origin Policy (perhaps CORS has relaxed things too far?). In either case, it seems that this attack vector is pretty minor in comparison to what other things an attacker could do in such situations. Oh, and if you have a "follow a link and delete data" situation, that has nothing to do with CSRF. It's entirely a problem with how a site was implemented to handle "deep linking" (i.e. preserving the state of an unauthenticated request to later replay it after successful authentication---as a convenience for end-users).

**What do you lose from using State in this manner?**

You cannot support IdP-initiated SSO. When the browser/end-user is already at the IdP and wants to SSO into the RP, the IdP would be unable to do it *in a single redirect*. The solution/workaround must involve the browser hitting the RP, then going back to the IdP, then finally returning again to the RP.