# What if authorization code in Oauth is leaked

Tags: oauth, authorization, single-sign-on, access-token

As soon as I log in successfully to the authentication server, the server redirects back to the application with an authorization code. And then this authorization code is used to get the access token in the backend. My doubt is if somebody has seen/captured or copied my authorization code before I have used it. Then he can also login with my credential. I want to know, Is it correct what I am thinking? Or I am missing some security flow in the process.

Edit: I am mostly concerned with the case where somebody has seen the authorization code in my browser history, and then he is sending this  code from other machine to get access token. How can we prevent it.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct: this is why in OAuth 2.0 there *should* be a fixed, registered callback URI that the Client receives the Authorization Code on, which is enforced by profiles such as OpenID Connect. The security considerations section of the specification analyzes the risks of the authorization code concept in more depth: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.5

Comment: so if the authorization code was captured after the auth server sent it to the user but before the client triggered the exchange, and the evil user that captured the code, trigger in his own user agent the call to the client with the code before the legitimate user, the client preform the exchange and now the evil user has gained access to the client . usually the code send insecure http, so how to mitigate this?

Comment: "state" is used to prevent that and bind the request/response cryptographically to the browser of the user, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.1

Comment: many thanks, also found this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165793/what-prevents-the-state-parameter-in-openid-connect-server-flow

Comment: @Ron87k Could you explain how using state mitigates the risk of a bad actor capturing the auth code in browser history? As understand, state helps ensure that my SPA doesn't forward auth codes to my backend server, by ensuring that the request wasn't INITIATED by a bad actor. I don't see how it helps with that bad actor observing that auth code, and making their own request (curl) to my backend sever.

Answer (score -2):

Your client's secret [is required](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.1) to exchange authorization code for access token. So if you keep your client secret at your backend, the attacker may be able to capture your authorization code, but won't be able to get access token.

Then, a lot depends on your redirect uri. If it belongs to your server, is https (so attacker won't able to [listen the traffic](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.9)) and your server doesn't allow [OpenRedirect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.15) - the attacker will probably fail to capture the code.

Next, authorization codes are expected to be [single-use](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.5). So if attacker finds the code in your browser history - this code is probably have been exchanged for token - that's why it can not be used once more time.

Please note that here I assume well-designed OAuth 2.0. OAuth 2.0 implementations that ignore the requirements of [RFC 4749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) can be subject to a large variety of attacks.

Comment: a client secret is not required i.e for public clients; also: the attacker may steal the code and present it to the original client in a so called "confused deputy" attack

Comment: You are certainly right: public clients do not require client secret (or store it unsafely); they also usually have unsafe redirect uri (i.e. with custom urlscheme). But as far as I understood it's not the case that @Avaneesh Kumar describes. Point on confused deputy attack is vaild for this case, thanks for clarification.