# PHP: Calling DocuSign userinfo endpoint after OAuth returns an "unauthorized_client" error

Tags: php, docusignapi

I want to get the user info (and user id in particular) after having my user go through the OAuth flow.

I try to obtain an access code from the return "code" queryparameter, but I get an "unauthorized_client" error

Here is my relevant code:

```
$url = 'https://account.docusign.com/oauth/token'; 
$cURLConnection = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//create basic authorization
$integration_key = '...2dee';
$secret_key = '...c11a';
$headers = array(
   "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($integration_key . ':' . $secret_key)
);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$body = array(
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
    "code" => $_REQUEST['code']
);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

$access_token = json_decode(curl_exec($cURLConnection), true);
print_r($access_token);
```

The error is provided by the print_r of $access_token

Thanks!

Comment: In oauth2/openId Connect, the userinfo endpoint must be called by providing the access_token. Take a look to the dev page : https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/

Comment: @svgta Thank you, I have updated my code and the question above, I get a different error now

Comment: $body is an PHP array. You can't send it like that in the curl. Try sending http_build_query($body)

Comment: I have tried that, but still with the same result (even after adding Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded to the header)

Comment: Have the possibility to install the client postman to test ? That can help a lot to verify all the authentication process.

Comment: Can you try to use the PHP package (SDK)? it will make this easier for you

Comment: Question: are you using the production or developer env?

Comment: @svgta using postman gives me the exact same error

Comment: @InbarGazit I am using the production environment (for the oauth as well as generating the token). The SDK might be an option, but this should work too, no?

Comment: I don't know what is the config you made in postman, but you have to choose oauth 2 in authorization and complete "configure new token", then click on "Get New Access Token". If it's don't work, you may be have a problem with your client_id and client_secret.

Comment: @svgta it must be something like that. I have now created a new secret key and still the same problem. However, when I change 1 character in the secret key, I get the same error as well...

Comment: I do see now that in the documentation, they also pass a "state" parameter to the oauth. The value of that parameter is pretty vague to me as it is described as "Redirect URIs cannot contain fragment components. If your app needs to use a fragment, record that fragment in the state parameter (which will be returned along with the redirect URI) and re-combine the fragment and the redirect URI in your app after the initial call to get the authorization code." So currently we are not passing a state parameter, might that be the problem? If so, what value should I give it?

Comment: The state is a random value you generate when calling the authorization endpoint for each request. In your callback url, you receive back the state and have to check it. It's a security : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165793/what-attack-does-the-state-parameter-in-openid-connect-server-flow-prevent

Comment: Another think : try the authorization process on https://account-d.docusign... it's for dev to test. May be your account is not yet available for the prod

Comment: our account is in production and we have other calls running perfectly there, so that shouldn't be the issue. I have however tried in the demo environment and get the same result there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you're sending the POST request's body encoded as JSON. That's not right, according to both the OAuth standards and the DocuSign documentation, the body must use form encoding:

1. Set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
2. See the [example request body](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/)

```
...
--data "grant_type=authorization_code&code=eyJ0eXAi.....QFsje43QVZ_gw"
```